# Не могу больше ничего установить, пишет ошибки зависимостей

Tags: linux, ubuntu

например, пытаюсь установить skype - `sudo apt-get install skype` ,
мне в консоли ответ:

> Возможно, для исправления этих ошибок вы захотите воспользоваться «apt-get -f install»:
>   Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
>    libllvm3.5:i386 : Зависит: libedit2:i386 (>= 2.11-20080614) но он не будет установлен
>   E: Неудовлетворённые зависимости. Попытайтесь выполнить «apt-get -f install», не указывая имени пакета, (или найдите другое решение).

`sudo apt-get -f install` - не помогает, ответ:

```
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 517935 файлов и каталогов.)
Preparing to unpack …/libedit2_3.1-20140620-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+4_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libedit2:i386 (3.1-20140620-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libedit2_3.1-20140620-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+4_i386.deb (--unpack):
 попытка перезаписать общий «/usr/share/doc/libedit2/changelog.Debian.gz», который отличается от других экземпляров пакета libedit2:i386
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libedit2_3.1-20140620-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+4_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Все произошло, после того как я пытался обновить скайп.

Comment: А как вы пытались его обновить? Он же сам обновляется.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/293693/how-to-install-skype-with-ubuntu-13-04 примерно так

Comment: Там не обновляется, а устанавливается. Вы делали по второму методу, да?

Comment: Да, возможно, это просто было какое-то время назад.. И, если не ошибаюсь, то предварительно удалил скайп

Comment: @АрмандГрундманис: Вы ж хотите точный ответ, а не «там примерно была какая-то команда», да? Тогда дайте точные подробности вопроса.

Comment: @VladD Я не могу точно сказать, потому что это произошло какое-то время назад

Comment: @АрмандГрундманис, переустановите ОС.

Comment: @LEQADA, впервые вижу совет переустановить линукс о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy, а что ещё делать? ТС не знает, что делал, как делал. Мне лень бегать за гадальным шаром.

Comment: @АрмандГрундманис: А как вы ожидаете, что мы сможем ответить? Проэкспериментируйте тогда. Вложите усилия в ваш вопрос.

Comment: А ты случайно не пытался установить 32-битные пакеты на 64-битный линукс?

Comment: @Qwertiy *А ты случайно не пытался установить 32-битные пакеты?* — да, если до этого вторая архитектура не была явно объявлена, то будут проблемы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я просто один раз скачал дистрибутив тимвьювера 32-битный и после попытки его поставить кончилось тем же - ничего больше не ставится, какие-то сообщения об ошибках установки пакетов. Ну и при той установке я, естественно, нажал игнорировать, когда система сказала, что пакеты не являются доверенными. Это была виртуалка, так что не особо жалко.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

1. попробуйте удалить проблемный пакет с помощью *dpkg*:

   ```
   $ sudo dpkg -r --force-depends libedit2:i386
   ```
2. а затем обновите список пакетов:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. и установите недостающие зависимости:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get -f install
   ```

---

обновление.

если у вас установлены (как основные) пакеты 64-битной архитектуры, а 32-битная архитектура не объявлена явно, то, вероятно, это и является проблемой. вам надо сначала добавить архитектуру, а уже потом выполнять шаги 2 и 3.

основную архитектуру можно посмотреть командой:

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
```

посмотреть «чужие» архитектуры можно так:

```
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures 
i386
armhf
```

добавить новую архитектуру можно так:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

удалить:

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

подробнее про мульти-архитектурность в *debian-основных* дистрибутивах можно почитать, например, [здесь](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO).

Answer (score 0):

Последний ответ не помог, но помог этот вариант:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/251630/apt-get-f-install-simply-not-working

Вместо `ARCHIVE.DEB` , я прописал `libedit2_3.1-20140620-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+4_i386.deb`

Всем спасибо