# Проблема при установке 32-bit приложения на 64-bit ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elf

Пытаюсь установить 32-bit приложение на 64-bit ubuntu. Судя по много численным комментариям - это реально. Уже установил пару библиотек, после которых должно все работать. Однако теперь вылетает ошибка при попытке запустить скрипт для установке:

> /user_path/bin/game.i386: error while loading shared libraries: libtbb.so.2: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Заранее благодарю за подсказки и советы:)

Comment: прочитайте после слова [обновление](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/475674/178576)

Comment: Можете попробовать старым способом -- пакет `ia32-libs`, а можно новым, на который выше @alexanderbarakin сослался.

Answer (score 0):

Egor Pavlov, к сожалению (или к счастью) я не знаком с дистром ubuntu. И, тем не менее, совет - для "совместного" запуска 32 и 64-битных приложений на 64-битной операционной системе - используйте **multilib** сборки. Не знаю, как для ubuntu, но для Linux Funtoo (мой любимый дистр) - это обозначается на этапе установки.

**А если нет такого?**

Ищите в инете тему по установке "32-разрядных либ на 64-битный хост под Ubuntu". Наверняка есть пакет, или ряд пакетов. Увы, с системой дистрибуцией в Ubuntu я не знаком, но что-то подобное быть должно.

Ну вот как-то так.